# echarts legend.itemGap only works on gulp browser-sync

Tags: javascript, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync, echarts

I want to reduce the gap between elements in my legend. I am using browser-sync and the time I'm using it it works but then I close browser-sync and open the same webapp and it doesn't seem to work.
This is my graph using browser-sync
[image: my graph using browser-sync]

And this is the graph after closing browrser-sync

[image: my graph without browser-sync]

This is my Echart option:

```
option ={
            title: {
                text: 'Ejercicios realizados por el paciente',
                left: 'center'
            },
            tooltip : {
                trigger: 'item'
            },
            toolbox: {
                show : true,
                /*orient: 'vertical',*/
                showTitle: true,
                feature : {
                    mark : {show: true},
                    /*magicType: {
                        show: true, 
                        type: ['line', 'bar', 'stack'],
                        title: {
                        line: 'linea',
                        bar: 'barras',
                        stack: 'barras apiladas'
                        }
                        },
                        restore : {
                        show: true,
                        title: 'restaurar'
                    },*/
                    saveAsImage : {
                        show: true,
                        title: 'captura'
                    }
                }
            },
            calculable : true,
            legend: {
                orient: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                top: '7%',
                right: '1%',
                left: /*'right'*/'80%',
                width: '27%',
                data:[],
                itemGap: 4,
                itemHeight: 7,
                itemWidth: 15,
                padding: 1,
                //backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'
            },
            xAxis: [
                {
                    type : 'category',
                    data: timeData,
                    //boundaryGap: ['20%', '40%']
                }
            ],
            yAxis: {
                type: 'value',
                name: 'N. veces',
                offset: 0,
                nameRotate: 0,
                fontSize: 12,
            },
            dataZoom: [{
                type: 'inside',
                start: 85,
                end: 100
                }, {
                start: 0,
                end: 10,
                handleIcon: 'M10.7,11.9v-1.3H9.3v1.3c-4.9,0.3-8.8,4.4-8.8,9.4c0,5,3.9,9.1,8.8,9.4v1.3h1.3v-1.3c4.9-0.3,8.8-4.4,8.8-9.4C19.5,16.3,15.6,12.2,10.7,11.9z M13.3,24.4H6.7V23h6.6V24.4z M13.3,19.6H6.7v-1.4h6.6V19.6z',
                handleSize: '100%',
                handleStyle: {
                    color: '#fff',
                    shadowBlur: 3,
                    shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
                    shadowOffsetX: 2,
                    shadowOffsetY: 2
                },
                bottom: '1%'
            }],
            grid: {
                //top: 110,
                left: '4%',
                right: '19%',
                //height: 160,
                width: '76%',
                containLabel: false,
            },
            series: [],
            color: ['#c23531','#2f4554', '#61a0a8', '#d48265', '#91c7ae','#749f83',  '#ca8622', '#bda29a','#6e7074', '#546570', '#c4ccd3', '#ff0065', '#71167a', '#fbe562', '#08331d', '#ADFF2F', '#cb6c00', '#421c25', '#25365c', '#8FBC8F', '#4169E1', '#FF4500']
        }
```

Did I miss something? Please help

Comment: have you tried using a custom `formatter` for the Legend. `legend` in echarts can be plenty tricky. I have struggled myself with similar issues and then settled for less desirable solutions over time considering not all of those issues could be resolved. You can also try setting different values for top/bottom and left/right padding (using arrays). Could you check the width of the `<div>`? is it a static value? If not could you see what the width is while `browser-sync` use vs. regular mode?

Answer (score 1):

Would try a change the values ​​of the options of the legend, **itemGap: 4, itemHeight: 7, itemWidth: 15**. With these settings, you'll be able to adapt it to the environment in which you want to run it

Comment: Thanks for your help but that's not the problem, I've changed those parameters to make the chart look like the fist one. I rebuild my webapp and run browser sync and it works as expected. The problem comes when I've just run the webapp in a regular mode, sin browser sync. It ignores the space parameters I've just typed.